# Drag and Drop often misses the DropEvent when running from PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, pyside2

I'm developping a PySide2 app where I can drag and drop items from one "bin" to another in PyCharm.

I have some rough code that I started to play with, and I can sort of Drag and Drop items from one bin to the other, but it only works in certain situations (I could not define what makes it work or not. Moving the mouse slowly seems to work better, but not always, and it seems to work better and better the more times it succeeded).

From the print statements I dropped in there it seems like sometimes it decides to trigger the dragLeaveEvent instead of dropEvent.

This is only happening when the Qt App is run from pycharm. If I run from outside PyCharm everything works fine.

I'm working on linux, using PySide2 5.12.0 PyCharm CE 2018.1.4 and Python 2.7.5.

I'm also working via VNC, which might affect the drag and drop? But I have no issue in other applications/standalone.

```
class MyLabel(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    def __init__(self, text, parent=None):
        super(MyLabel, self).__init__(text, parent)

        self.setStyleSheet("""
           background-color: black;
           color: white;
           font: bold;
           padding: 6px;
           border-width: 2px;
           border-style: solid;
           border-radius: 16px;
           border-color: white;
       """)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        itemData   = QtCore.QByteArray()
        dataStream = QtCore.QDataStream(itemData, QtCore.QIODevice.WriteOnly)
        dataStream.writeString(self.text())
        dataStream << QtCore.QPoint(event.pos() - self.rect().topLeft())

        mimeData = QtCore.QMimeData()
        mimeData.setData('application/MyWindow', itemData)
        mimeData.setText(self.text())

        drag = QtGui.QDrag(self)
        drag.setMimeData(mimeData)
        drag.setHotSpot(event.pos() - self.rect().topLeft())

        self.hide()
        drag.setPixmap(self.grab())

        if drag.exec_(QtCore.Qt.MoveAction | QtCore.Qt.CopyAction, QtCore.Qt.CopyAction) == QtCore.Qt.MoveAction:
            self.close()

        else:
            self.show()


class TrackBin(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, track_name):
        super(TrackBin, self).__init__()
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        # Header
        header = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        header.setFrameStyle(header.StyledPanel | header.Raised)
        header.setLayout(QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout())
        header.layout().addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel(track_name))

        layout.addWidget(header)

        # Content area (scrollable)
        self.bin_content = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        scroll_area = QtWidgets.QScrollArea()
        scroll_area.setWidgetResizable(True)
        scroll_area_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        scroll_area_widget.setLayout(QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout())
        scroll_area_widget.layout().addLayout(self.bin_content)
        scroll_area_widget.layout().addStretch()
        scroll_area.setWidget(scroll_area_widget)
        for _i in range(5):
            self.bin_content.addWidget(MyLabel("some text"))

        layout.addWidget(scroll_area)

        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        print "drag enter"
        e.accept()

    def dragLeaveEvent(self, e):
        print "drag leave"
        print e
        e.accept()

    def dropEvent(self, e):
        print e

        e.setDropAction(QtCore.Qt.MoveAction)
        e.accept()
        self.handle_drop(e)

    def handle_drop(self, e):
        print e
        print e.isAccepted()
        print e.source()
        # Was trying moving the event.source() directly but doesn't seem to work?
        self.bin_content.addWidget(MyLabel(e.source().text()))
```

(full code here: https://pastebin.com/Jn9kgqM5)

I'm expecting that the drop would work every time, not just randomly.

Does anyone know how to make it work from pycharm? (Or is anyone even having the same issue)

Comment: What is your question? You could explain what does not work. I have tested your code and its code works correctly

Comment: Thank you for testing. I believe it is not working because of the way I am developping via a VNC connection and running directly from PyCharm, I think something gets broken there. I ran my code in standalone from outside PyCharm and it works as expected. So I don't actually have a question anymore.

Comment: It may be, I do not use VNC, maybe there is a delay that generates that when you release the mouse it is in another position.

Comment: I am not sure if it because of VNC or PyCharm. Should I delete the question or edit it to ask about PyCharm issue instead? (I think it would be PyCharm, since running in standalone or another host Qt application works fine, even through VNC)

Comment: Edit it giving more emphasis to the VNC and pycharm. On the other hand, it proves if the same thing happens with PyQt5 so it could be ruled out that the cause of the problem is not PySide2.

Comment: Edited the question to be more about running from PySide.